# Spring 2.0.0 - migrate gives error: NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/mapper/JacksonMappingProvider

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When migrating my Spring Boot 1.4.3-release application to Spring Boot 2.0.0. I get this error:

> NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/mapper/JacksonMappingProvider

The Spring Boot Parent has the 2.0.0. The jsonpath jayway has the 2.2.0 version.

For the Jsonpath I use. I want to scan parts of the JSON, not map the whole json string to objects ... in this case.

```
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.JSONValue;
```

What I am doing wrong?

**SOLVED: there were 2 issues:**

1. See below thanks to @Barath -- json-path for Spring Boot 2.0.0 needs at least the 2.4.0 version.
2. While upgrading the source part to Spring Boot 2.0.0 I forgot to remove the older version specification for the spring-boot-starter-test.

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
standard init

  <!-- Use parent POM.xml -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.13.3</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Chat websocket stuff -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database for Openshift -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.40</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON path -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <!--<version>1.9</version>-->
      <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
      <!--<version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>-->
    </dependency>

    <!-- TESTING -->

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>geosolutions</finalName>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
              <executable>npm</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>install</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>build Angular production code</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
              <executable>npm</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>run</argument>
                <argument>build</argument>
                <argument>--prod</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- for testing -->
      <...>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: how about spring-boot-test dependency??

Comment: When skipping the tests?

Comment: Jsonpath comes as part of spring boot starter test isn't it ? Do you require for some other purpose as you defined explicitly ?

Comment: Yes, I use these classes: import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.JSONValue;

Comment: As I checked in pom spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE. json path mentioned is   `<json-path.version>2.4.0</json-path.version>`. can you change it to 2.4.0 and try ?

Comment: @Barath - thank you!. This was 1 part of the solution. The other part was that I had an older version in the spring-boot-starter-test. >>> Can you put your suggestions (both) in the answer? Then I will +1 / V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of Spring-Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE, json-path version to be used is `2.4.0`

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```